# Transposing Rows and Columns in BigQuery SQL using PIVOT and UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to transpose rows and columns in BigQuery using PIVOT followed by UNPIVOT.

Original Table:

| month | metric1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00 | 12 |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00 | 20 |
| 2023-02-01T00:00:00 | 11 |

Expected Table:

|  | 2022-12-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| metric1 | 12 | 20 | 11 |

I have tried performing an UNPIVOT on the original table first:

```
SELECT * FROM original_table 
UNPIVOT(value for metric IN (metric1))
```

which gave me the following results:

| month | value | metric |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01T00:00:00 | 12 | metric1 |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00 | 20 | metric1 |
| 2023-02-01T00:00:00 | 11 | metric1 |

Afterwards, I have tried performing a PIVOT on the resulting table:

```
SELECT * FROM final
PIVOT(MIN(value) for month IN (DATETIME '2022-12-01', DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-02-01'))
```

But this gave an error:

```
Query error: PIVOT values of type DATETIME must specify an alias at [21:32]
```

How can I fix this error? Or is there a more efficient way to transpose the rows and columns?

Add on: My original table (unsimplified version) has more metrics as the columns (ie. metric1, metric2, etc). Was also wondering how the code would look like if there are more metrics in place.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your table has more metrics, how do you expect your output table look like ?

Comment: Hi @Jaytiger, I'm expecting the output table to look similar to the Expected Table shown in the question, with the subsequent metrics as new rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this syntax and will garner the same result:

```
PIVOT(MIN(value) for DATE(month) IN ('2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01'))
```

Output:

[image]

But if you want to keep the approach in using `DATETIME` which is specifically an answer to your question, you try this approach:

```
PIVOT(MIN(value) for DATETIME(month) IN (DATETIME('2022-12-01T00:00:00') as _2022_12_01, DATETIME('2023-01-01T00:00:00') as _2023_01_01, DATETIME('2023-02-01T00:00:00') as _2023_02_01))
```

The `alias` which are the `_2022_12_01`, `_2023_01_01`, and `_2023_02_01` are necessary to declare since you want to represent items in your query.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can consider below

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT '2022-12-01T00:00:00' month,   12 metric1, 24 metric2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-01-01T00:00:00', 20, 40 metric2  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2023-02-01T00:00:00', 11, 22 metric2
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
    FROM sample_table UNPIVOT (value FOR metric IN (metric1, metric2))
) PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(value) FOR DATE(month) IN ('2022-12-01', '2023-01-01', '2023-02-01'));
```

**Query results**

[image]